# I want to change setting of internet explorer through pywin32

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32com

I want to change setting of explorer through pywin32
I am able to get url and data within browser but not getting way to access tool
and other setting options.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting task. I just don't know how submenu window is created in IE. The following code presses "Tools" menu button (IE 8), but I could not detect a menu window. Workaround is typing keys.

```
import pywinauto, time

app = pywinauto.Application().start_(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
main = app.Window_(title_re='^.* - Windows Internet Explorer$')

main.PageControlToolbar.PressButton(6) # stop loading, just in case
main.ToolbarFile.PressButton('&Tools')
time.sleep(1)
main.TypeKeys('{UP}{ENTER}')

app.InternetOptions.Wait('ready')
app.InternetOptions.TabControl.Select('Connections')
```

Ah, yes, [there's link to pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/). But the code above is checked on [development version of pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto), so original pywinauto 0.4.2 may not find "ToolbarFile" properly (use "Toolbar3" instead).

Comment: I know, this is incomplete answer, but comment with multi-line code doesn't look nice also.

Comment: Thanks for your short and helpful answer, Now I get the idea to look into right direction

Comment: Further steps need more specifics. But when "Internet Options" dialog is open, this is very simple now.

Comment: GetButtonInfo failed for button with command id 101 any idea ? for  main.PageControlToolbar.PressButton(6)

Comment: Which IE version? Which pywinauto version?

Comment: IE 8 pywinauto 0.4.0 and python 64bit, I think pywinauto does not support 64 bit

Comment: Yes, official pywinauto doesn't support 64-bit. My clone supports it: https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto-64 Also if IE8 process is 32-bit (see in Task Manager), 32-bit Python is required anyway.